# Change list of allowed headline levels in Gutenberg

Tags: block-editor

is there any way (eg. a hook) to disallow some headline levels in Gutenberg. For example, I would like to disallow a user to use H1 level.

By default, headline levels H1-H6 are visible. [image: Headline level in Gutenberg]

I wasn't able to Google this out